# How to stop re-rendering of child component when its parent's props change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `Modal` that is a child of a `Card` component:

```
Card > Modal
```

The `Card` has props that it sends down to the `Modal`. When I select an option in the `Modal`'s UI, it updates the data in the `Card` and, thus, re-renders the `Card`, closing the `Modal` as it does so.

This is not ideal because I would like the user to continue to use the `Modal` until they explicitly hit "close".

Is there a way to update the data/state in the underlying `Card` (so that the `Modal` can use the new state), but NOT trigger a full re-render of the component tree until the `Modal` is finally closed?

There is no Redux involved right now, and I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Can you share some code, ideally a working fiddle.

Comment: Sure, let me see what I can do.

Comment: @WebstraDev - Would a video walkthrough be okay?

Comment: You might have to stop calling the parent update function which is auto updating the data. Instead update them after all the changes have been done. (The idea is they have to have different state so that the data doesn't interfere with each other) or another idea would be adding a identifier to identify where the request is coming from and act accordingly

Comment: Please explore if either `useMemo` or `useCallback` may be suitable to your specific issue (to stop re-rendering child when parent's state changes).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a state is updated, all components that use the state and its children are re-rendered. You should probably use react portals to achieve what you need with the modal. There is a fiddle on the end of the docs link.
Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html